# How to vertically center text with larger icon?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, vertical-alignment

I am using a Font Awesome icon in the modal of success. I want to make the icon bigger, the problem is the text is no longer vertically centered if I do that.

[image]

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
  <span class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 32px;"></span>
  <strong> You have successfully set up an administration for this client.</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: `vertical-align: middle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align`:

```
.fa {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akwcjc8p/)**

Or, use flexbox:

```
.alert {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5khbsjwm/)**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Text alignment - class="text-center"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/)   and [class="align-middle"](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/)

```
 <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible text-center">
     <span class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 32px;"></span>
     <strong class="align-middle"> You have successfully set up an administration for this client.</strong>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox solution

```
.alert{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Hope this helps.